# Run flyway migrations inside Java code during runtime

Tags: java, jdbc, flyway

I want to be able to run Flyway migrations inside my Java code during runtime, is there a way of achieving this? I can't seem to be able to find it in the docs. I'm using a SQLite database (if this matters at all).

Comment: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/#programmatic-configuration-java ?

Comment: @giorgiga I must have missed that, but it's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## `Flyway::migrate()`

Call [`Flyway::migrate`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#migrate--).

To quote the [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/api):

```
package foobar;

import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create the Flyway instance and point it to the database
        Flyway flyway = 
                Flyway.configure()
                      .dataSource( "jdbc:h2:file:./target/foobar" , "scott" , "tiger" )  // (url, user, password)
                      .load()                                                            // Returns a `Flyway` object.
        ;

        // Start the migration
        flyway.migrate();

    }
}
```