# Spring application with embedded file based H2 multi tennant databases and manual migrations

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, h2, flyway

My use case and business requirements ara a bit unusual, so bear with me :)

I am building a desktop app using `Spring boot`. Now for supporting offline work it has to have a embedded local file based database, but here it gets tricky, because client app has to support multiple different users, and their data shouldn't collide (
meaning users should be able to delete their own specific database easily) so they either should be separated in different databases or schemas.
Since the **number or identity** of the users using the app is not predetermined schemas or databases need to be created dinamically on login action. After database/schema is created for the user migrations need to be ran to create appropriate tables and fetch the data from server.

I've successfully set up multi tennant app but only managed to get it working with predefined databases. And yet another challenge is to run `flyway` migrations manually during the runtime.

I've searched the web for references but no luck

Answer (score 2):

This should help [Run flyway migrations inside Java code during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728391/run-flyway-migrations-inside-java-code-during-runtime). You can now choose to trigger this action wherever you desire in your application and passing database/schema name as variable to your bean method

Comment: Thanks, this seems to help with FlyWay issue.